# Check all entries from current page Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

If I click the `Select all` checkbox, all entries will be selected. But if I have a list of users containing 50 users and I paginate them 5 per page, if I press the checkbox, they will be all selected, not just the entries on the selected page. How can I resolve this? This is a snippet of my code.

.html

```
<table class="spacing-table table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <label class="customcheck">
          <input type="checkbox" (change)="selectAll()">
          <span class="checkmark">Select all</span>
        </label>
      </th>
      <th id="table-header">Name</th>
      <th id="table-header">Group</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of usersList | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }">
        <td>
          <label class="customcheck">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark">Select all</span>
          </label>
        </td>
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.group}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p=$event" previousLabel="Previous" nextLabel="Next"></pagination-controls>
```

.ts

```
isSelected: boolean = false
selectAll() {
    this.isSelected = !this.isSelected
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once and the way to achieve it is make an array of paginated data instead of using the pipe for pagination and then write a logic in the controller to find the current page and update the selections for that page.

User this page service for creating paginated data

```
export class TablePageService {
constructor() {
}

getPager(totalItems: number, currentPage: number = 1, pageSize: number) {
    // calculate total pages
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

    const startPage = 1;
    const endPage = totalPages;

    // calculate start and end item indexes
    const startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
    const endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);
    // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
    const pages = this.range(startPage, endPage);
   // return object with all pager properties required by the view
    return {
        totalItems,
        currentPage,
        pageSize,
        totalPages,
        startPage,
        endPage,
        startIndex,
        endIndex,
        pages,
    };
}

range(lowEnd, highEnd) {
    const arr = [];
    let c = highEnd - lowEnd + 1;
    while ( c-- ) {
        arr[c] = highEnd--;
    }
    return arr;
   }
}
```

and in your controller you can define a setPage method, where the pagedItems will give you the current set of pages on display

```
public setPage(page: number) {

this.pager = this.tablePageService.getPager(
  this.tableContentList.length,
  page,
  this.tableConfig.pageSize
);

if (page < 1 || (page > this.pager.totalPages && page !== 1)) {
  return;
}
this.pagedItems = this.tableContentList.slice(this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.endIndex + 1);
if (this.pagedItems.length < this.pager.pageSize) {
  this.substituteItems = Array.from({
    length: this.tableConfig.pageSize - this.pagedItems.length,
  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how your pagination extension works but what you actually can do is to either `extend each userObject with an isSelected option` or `hold an external array for the selections`.

I purpose the second version:

```
<table class="spacing-table table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <label class="customcheck">
          <input type="checkbox" (change)="selectAll(p)">
          <span class="checkmark">Select all</span>
        </label>
      </th>
      <th id="table-header">Name</th>
      <th id="table-header">Group</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of usersList; let i=index | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }">
        <td>
          <label class="customcheck">
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isSelected[i]">
            <span class="checkmark">Select all</span>
          </label>
        </td>
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.group}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p=$event" previousLabel="Previous" nextLabel="Next"></pagination-controls>
```

Now you need to trigger the selections manually in your controller like this:

```
isSelected: boolean[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.isSelected = [];
    for(let i=0; i<this.userList.length; i++) {
        this.isSelected.push(false);
    }
}

selectAll(page: number) {
    // deselect all because of page changes
    for(let i=0; i<this.usersList.length; i++) {
        this.isSelected[i] = false;
    }

    // select all on current page
    for(let i=5*(p-1); i<5*(p-1)+5; i++) {
        if(i <= this.usersList.length-1) {
            this.isSelected[i] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe this answer gives you some hints for an own answer.

Comment: On the first page, the indexes will be 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 on the second page 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 etc. Why?

Comment: My fault, I updated my answer to the following `for(let i=5*(p-1); i<5*(p-1)+5; i++)`. If `page 1` is input it will iterate from `0 to 4`, if `page 2` is input it will iterate from `5 to 9` which should be the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you, I was never good at numbers. Now I get the right indexes, but it's weird because `this.isSelected[i] = true` has the right value, if I am on the second page, I will have true on indexes 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. But it's not working, they won't be selected :(

Comment: Did you tried to output `{{ isSelected[i] | json }}` inside the `*ngFor` ? Maybe the paginate pipe does not work properly with `let i=index`. An alternative would be adding `isSelected` as an attribute to the users array that you can call `user.isSelected` directly or to map the `isSelected` array to the user id or something similar.